# MariaDB prevent delete when value not 1

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I want to create a trigger that prevents the deletion of a row when a value is not 1.

My table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `t_rechnung` (
    `rechnungsnummer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `rechnungsdatum` DATE NOT NULL,
    `bezahlt` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`rechnungsnummer`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

All triggers I tried are not working due to them being specific to MySQL.

Edit:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_test 
BEFORE DELETE ON t_rechnung
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF bezahlt <> 1 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE 
END IF;
END //
```

I tried this.

```sql
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF bezahlt <> 1 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000' SET MYSQL_ERRNO=42000, MESSAGE_TEXT='Unable to delete unpaid bills!';
END IF
END
```

And this.

Comment: . . You should show an example of the trigger that you have tried.  The syntax is pretty similar so it is unclear why your attempt would not work.

Comment: ok. Made an edit.

Comment: . . A trigger would normally refer to `new` and/or `old`.

Comment: . . I have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: @GhostJumper - Read more about Triggers.  They use two pseudo tables called `OLD` and `NEW` to refer to the values of the row before and after the operation executes.  You probably need `OLD.bezahlt` instead of simply `bezahlt`.